# tensorflow gpu fails to install

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

I'm using Python 3.7, and it seems every solution I searched is on Conda environment, which is, I don't use.
My computer spec is intel i7 with nvidia gtx1050, and when I used the command "pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu" in command line, it always fires this error.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu
```

Anyone can help? I have CUDA Toolkit 9.2 installed, and the latest cuDNN installed. I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: TensorFlow supports only Python 3.5.x and 3.6.x on Windows as per the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows. I would suggest  you to install it using anaconda .

Answer (score 1):

When I search “TensorFlow” in https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/#files
I find the following information:

> tensorflow-1.8.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl    Wheel   **cp36**    Apr 28, 2018

Till 2018-07-09, only **python(<=3.6)** could find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow.

I think if you want to use TensorFlow, maybe you should lower you Python version.

I found a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow.
And I write down the method in the another answer on this page.

Comment: Wait, let me try it with python 3.6.6, maybe it will work

Answer (score 0):

2018-07-30
I found tensorflow-1.9 for Python3.7 (tensorflow‑1.9.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl)

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow

You would find this on the website:

> TensorFlow, computation using data flow graphs for scalable machine learning.
>   Requires numpy+mkl and protobuf. The CUDA builds require **CUDA 9.2 and CUDNN 9.2**.
>   tensorflow‑1.9.0‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
>   tensorflow‑1.9.0‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

---

other version of TensorFlow.whl

https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is support only on Python 3.5.X versions. Try installing on any of these versions. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up, Tensorflow GPU WONT WORK with CUDA toolkit v9.2, you need to download and install v9.0.  It's available by clicking 'legacy downloads' on the Cuda download page.  TF looks for a specific file (cudart64_90.dll) that is from 9.0 and won't accept the equivalent version of the library (cudart64_92.dll) from the latest 9.2 version.  The good news is that you DO NOT have to uninstall v9.2 of the toolkit, the Nvidia installer will just add a separate v9.0 folder in the Nvidia Cuda directory right next to the v9.2 folder you already have.  I hope this helps.